# What is the most efficient way to handle merge conflicts on your compiled SASS css file?

Tags: css, git, merge, sass

I am working on a project with several developers that uses SASS, Drupal, and Git. We currently are keeping the compiled CSS file in version control. The problem is that every time a developer pulls they get merge conflicts on that compiled CSS file.

Since that file is created by compiling the SASS files, it doesn't matter how we resolve the conflicts in this file, but we have to each time.

We aren't able to set up any kind of automated compilation on the dev/test/live environments, so we have to keep the compiled file in version control so it gets deployed.

Are there any kind of commit hook (or other) options that would also just resolve conflicts in this using theirs or yours (it doesn't matter)?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend never to commit compiled files (wether they are css, C, or whatever) into a VCS. Everyone should be able to compile them theirself and with git you could setup a [`post-checkout`-hook](http://schacon.github.com/git/githooks.html#_post_checkout)

Update: Just read

> We aren't able to set up any kind of automated compilation on the dev/test/live environments, so we have to keep the compiled file in version control so it gets deployed.

thus I recommend to setup a deployment-strategy, that includes compiling of the sass files.

Comment: Recommending a "strategy" isn't really an answer. The post-checkout-hook is useful only for local, but doesn't completely answer how to compile on remote environments.

Comment: @AlxVallejo What isn't answered "completely"? I've never mentioned a "post-checkout-hook", but a "deployment strategy". For example I use capistrano to perform such tasks. If you don't automate your deployment ... yeah, than you know your flaw.